# SQLDependency with group by is not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

I have below code for SqlDependency. Below call back function is get called every time when data reader is executed. Rather than this call back function not get executing when i change some value in Table.

```
 public IEnumerable<Messages> GetAllMessages()
    {
        var messages = new List<Messages>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(MessageID) FROM [dbo].[Messages] group by Message", connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

               var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   // messages.Add(item: new Messages { MessageID = (int)reader["MessageID"], Message = (string)reader["Message"], EmptyMessage = reader["EmptyMessage"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["EmptyMessage"] : "", MessageDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]) });
                }
            }

        }
        return messages;
    }
```

**CallBack:**

```
 private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                MessagesHub.SendMessages();
            }
        }
```

Any Help please!

Comment: When do you expect the notification? Your command is `.Dispose()`d, and your dependency is local anyway. How do you manage to change data in the table while this function is running?

Comment: @nvoigt After execution of main function, i have changed some value in table. At that time i want to get notification. But now i am not getting.

Comment: No, obviously not. Neither your command nor your dependency survive the end of your posted function. For you to receive notifications, they should still be valid objects.

Comment: Maybe you miss the opening and closing of the dependency connection: SqlDependency.Start(connectionString) and SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString) ?

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I have already set those globally.

Comment: @nvoigt It will be valid object unless i stop the IIS,  Because dependency will be always in ON state.